# Yii не отправляет почту и падает

Tags: php, yii2, yii, email, sendmail

Есть такой код:

```
$letter = Yii::$app->gtrmailer->compose('views/confirm_user', ['name' => '', 'link' => $link] )
        ->setFrom(['no-reply@domain.com' => 'domain'])
        ->setTo($email)
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->send();
```

На этой строке крешится весь код. Где найти ошибку? Как посмотреть логи можно?

Настройки почты введены следующие:

```
'gtrmailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'enableSwiftMailerLogging' => true,
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'htmlLayout' => 'layouts/html_gtr',
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'mail.domain.com',
                'username' => 'no-reply@domain.com',
                'password' => 'password',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ]
```

Comment: На какой строке? Там их 5 штук. И какая ошибка?

Comment: Вопрос решился путем перенастройки соединения на другой тип через swiftmailer

Comment: Было бы неплохо дополнить вопрос ошибкой и написать в ответе решение. Возможно, это поможет кому-то еще.

Comment: Ошибка была следующей:
`код`2020-04-27 13:04:08 188.163.81.67 Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host mail.gotrening.com [Connection refused #61]`код`
чтобы включить вывод ошибок, нужно в /core/config/web.php в секцию log в targets добавить
`код` 'categories' => ['yii\swiftmailer\Logger::add'], `код`

исправилось все путем изменения типа доставки почты - в раздел components там же добавил:

        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        ],
и отправку писем делал уже через него:

`код` Yii::$app->mailer->compose() `код`

Comment: @fedornabilkin добавил вроде как